# $C^*$-algebra desription of the complex Clifford algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras, universal-algebra, clifford-algebras

I read somewhere a discription of the complex Clifford algebra as a $C^*$-algebra, but I don't know where...

Is the complex Clifford algebra the universal $C^*$-algebra generated by elements $1$ and $\epsilon$, where $\epsilon ^2=-1$, or what is the correct description?

Answer (score 1):

Complex Clifford algebras of nondegenerate forms are all isomorphic to square matrix rings over $\mathbb C$ or the square of such a ring. These are all $C^\ast$ algebras if you use regular Hermitian conjugation, if I remember correctly.